# How do you change the font size in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I inadvertently hit a key sequence that changed the font size in the SQL editor of Workbench, but I can't find a way to undo it.

Have found references to making changes in a text file to change the font size, but there must be an alternative way to make the change interactively as my "fat fingering" has proven...

I'm using version 5.2.47 CE Build 10398

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this board is about implementation specific issues, so programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

The editor font can be changed by editing this file if you are using windows:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\wb_options.xml
```

In the file, change the value below:

```
value type="string" key="workbench.general.Editor:Font Consolas 10
```

Comment: Anyone know how to change the font size of the result grid?